# Javascript cookies code not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was writing this code that is based on a tutorial and on the tutorial the code works, but when I try to do it by myself it doesn't. Can you help me ?

The code : ([Tutorial Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlvO2-T-yIQ)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var user_name;
            var expires = new Date();
            if ((document.cookie == "") == false)
            {
                var length = document.cookie.length - 1;
                var message = document.cookie.substr(5, length);
                document.write("<h2><center>Welcome back, " + message + "</center></h2>");
            }

            function check()
            {
                user_name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
                document.cookie = escape("name") + escape(user_name) + "; expires = " + expires.toGMTString();
                alert(document.cookie);
            }
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="check()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a poor tutorial. Can you link to it?

Comment: Yes, if that code is taken from a tutorial, definitely find another one.

Comment: don't waste time implementing this. Use jquery.cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlvO2-T-yIQ

Comment: @user2580136 I'd be wary of tutorials with comments disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've mentioned `I was creating this code that is tutorial based and on the tutorial`, so if it's just for a `test myself` thing then you may consider to use  this one ([**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yCNpQ/)), just enter a name and value for the cookie in the cookie name and cookie value fields respectively, when you want to `Add` a new cookie and to `Delete` a cookie just enter the name of the cookie in the cookie name field and same for `View`, you can add a `Delete All` buttons only by splitting cookies using `&` and making a loop and calling the `eraseCookie()` function, try it yourself.

Also there are already [better ones](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) are available on the web to use in the real case, but this one is not bad at all.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    return true;
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    if(!name) {
        alert('\nPlease enter the name of cookie in cookie the name field.');
        return false;
    }
    if(readCookie(name)){
        if(createCookie(name,"",-1)) {
            alert('Cookie "' + name + '" has been deleted!');        
        }
    }
    else alert('Cookie "' + name + '" doesn\'t exist!');
}

function addCookie()
{
    cookie_name = document.getElementById("cName").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    cookie_value = document.getElementById("cValue").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    if(cookie_name.length && cookie_value.length){
        createCookie(cookie_name, cookie_value, 7);
        alert("New cookie has been added, \ncookie name : " + cookie_name + "\ncookie value : " + cookie_value);
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a name and value for the cookie.");
    }
}

function showCookie(name)
{
    if(!name) {
        alert('\nPlease enter the name of cookie in the  cookie name field.');
        return false;
    }
    var val = readCookie(name);
    if(val){
        alert(readCookie(name));
    }
    else alert('Cookie "' + name + '" doesn\'t exist!');
}

// Onload to check and greet
if(name = readCookie('name')) alert('Welcome back, ' + name);
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yCNpQ/)

Comment: @user2580136, what's wrong ? this code is running in the givel fiddle link.